# How to add geojson data to Source and Layer Component of react-map-gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am using `react-map-gl` library to work with mapbox. I want to create a line over the map on some data points. Map is rendering fine but line is not showing on the map.

[Source link @Github with all description of the problem.](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1213)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coordinates should be a 2-dimensional array for LineString.

dataJS should look like this

```
const dataJS = {
  type: "Feature",
  properties: {},
  geometry: {
    type: "LineString",
    coordinates: [
      [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
      [-66.96466, 44.8097],
      [-68.03252, 44.3252],
      [-69.06, 43.98],
      [-70.11617, 43.68405],
      [-70.64573401557249, 43.090083319667144],
      [-70.75102474636725, 43.08003225358635],
      [-70.79761105007827, 43.21973948828747],
      [-70.98176001655037, 43.36789581966826],
      [-70.94416541205806, 43.46633942318431],
      [-71.08482, 45.3052400000002],
      [-70.6600225491012, 45.46022288673396],
      [-70.30495378282376, 45.914794623389355],
      [-70.00014034695016, 46.69317088478567],
      [-69.23708614772835, 47.44777598732787],
      [-68.90478084987546, 47.184794623394396],
      [-68.23430497910454, 47.35462921812177],
      [-67.79035274928509, 47.066248887716995],
      [-67.79141211614706, 45.702585354182816],
      [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886]
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: hi, i just used your example but, it didn't worked.
[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-albattani-frv7d?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Set cluster to false. Clustering only works for points: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson-cluster

Comment: I did what you said, but no improvement. 
[if you have time then please edit this on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-albattani-frv7d?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to change the default  latitude (37.830348) and longitude (122.486052). When the map loads, it doesn't "see" the line.